# infinite loop if pause java game

Tags: java

I have a part of my code:

```
while(_running){
   // render screens 
     if( _input.escape) {
          if( isPaused ) {                  
                 pauseDialog.setVisible(false);
                 remuse(); // set isPaused = false, _running = true and render screens
           }
           else {
                 pause(); // set isPaused = true and _running = false and render screens                        
                 pauseDialog.setVisible(true);
          }
     }
}
```

and _input like this

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;   
}
```

and pauseDialog

```
public class PauseDialog extends JDialog{
JButton b1,b2;
public PauseDialog() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1,8,8));
    setSize(new Dimension(85, 180));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    b1 = new JButton("resume");
    b2 = new JButton("exit");

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("resume");               
        }
    });
    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("exit");
        }
    });             
    add(b1); add(b2);
}
```

but if i setvisible(true) for pauseDialog when escape key is released, variable _input.escape is always set true value, so dialog appears and disappears and appears again ... like an infinite loop. what should i do next? thanks.

Comment: try e.preventDefault() inside the keyPressed and keyReleased function...

Comment: And just for the record: b1 and b2 are really bad names. Use names that tell the reader what the thing behind the variable is about.

Comment: Change `remuse` to `resume`.

Comment: Also, what is `_running`? You could just write `while(true)`.

Answer (score -1):

Set "_input.escape" to False, after Escape is pressed?

Or does "_input.escape" need to be True for pausing to happen?

If so, that implies something's wrong, 'cause you shouldn't need to hold down Escape to keep the game paused?

---

It just seems you need a good logic system so that the dialog isn't being triggered more than once.

Maybe check if it's already triggered and don't trigger it again?

Comment: Set true when pressed and false when releases and ive already set cooldown time between 2 times pause code which is called. But not working

Comment: @BlackW - Set so it changes state when pressed, instead of turning true when pressed and false when released...